# Syncfusion MVC Grid: How to render a dropdown in a specific cell with hardcoded values when adding a row to the grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

My grid has the feature of adding rows. I did it following [this documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/grid/editing)

How do I make that in a specific cell, it renders a dropdown with hardcoded values??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve your requirement using the actionCompelete event of ejGrid control and we have bound hardcoded values to that dropdown list.

For an example, we have render a ejDropDownList for ShipCountry column in Grid.

Refer the below code example.

```
@(Html.EJ().Grid<object>("FlatGrid")
    .Datasource((IEnumerable<object>)ViewBag.datasource)

    ---------

   .ClientSideEvents(clienevent => clienevent.ActionComplete("complete"))      
    .Columns(col =>
    {

       -----

        col.Field("ShipCountry").HeaderText("Ship Country").TextAlign(TextAlign.Right).Width(75).Add();


    }))

var data = [
    { id: "1", text: "FRANCE" }, 
    { id: "2", text: "GERMANY" }, 
    { id: "3", text: "BRAZIL" },
    { id: "4", text: "BELGIUM" }, 
    { id: "5", text: "MEXICO" }

];

function complete(args) {

    if (args.requestType == "add") {

        $("#" + this._id + "ShipCountry").ejDropDownList( { 

           dataSource: data, 

            field: { text: "text", value: "text" }, 
            width: "100%" 
        });
    }
}
```

Note: To bind the dataSource in ejDropDownList we need to pass  as the text and value pair.

We have prepared a sample and it can be downloadable from the below location.

Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/131894/ze/SyncfusionMvcApplication14-2117895693.zip